# Beginner Question: Is it bad to mix raster photography into vector based print work? Alternative?

Tags: print-design, vector, resize, raster

I am tasked with creating a vector based print work. And I'm very new to print design.

Is it a good idea to include raster photography inside my vector image? It seems to destroy the whole point of "infinite scalability". How do I create something that can be scalable, so as to be used on large outdoor banners and such?

Thanks for your help! I'm quite lost. :(

Answer (score 3):

There's not really a problem including raster images provided you know the final output.

Raster images, inside a vector app or not, always have the **same limitations** in terms of scaling. Placing a raster image into a vector app does *not* make it resolution independent.

With that in mind, it's really your call.

If you need infinite scalability, then you should avoid raster images in all cases.